# Вывод первого элемента двумерного массива

Tags: python

Есть код, в котором я создаю массив размерностью nxm, затем нужно найти число максимально близкое к среднему значению массива, сделал проверку, но у меня вместо элемента массива `s[0][0]` выводится `s[1][0]`

```
import math
    def main():
        m=int(input("Введите количество столбцов:"))
        n=int(input("Введите количество строк:"))
        s = [[0] * n] * m
        for i in range(0,m):
            for j in range(0,n):
                print("Введите элемент " , i , j)
                s[i][j]=int(input())
        print(s[0][0])
        print(matrix(s))
    def matrix(s):
        x = 0
        for i in range(len(s[:][:])):
            for j in range(len(s[:][0])):
                x +=s[i][j]
        x = x/(len(s[:][:])*len(s[:][0]))
        print("Avarage = " , x)
        buff=0
        result=0

        for i in range(len(s[:][:])):
            for j in range(len(s[:][0])):
                print(i)
                print(j)
                buff = math.fabs(x - math.fabs(s[i][j]))
                print(x,"-",math.fabs(s[i][j])," = ",buff)
                if result==0:
                    result=s[i][j]
                elif buff<result:
                    result=s[i][j]
        return result

    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так правильно. 4 ближе к 4,5, чем 2.

Comment: @Эникейщик прочитайте вопрос и поймёте как связан, и перестаньте грубить всем в комментариях

Comment: Прочитал, не беспокойтесь. Никак не связан. Вывод первого элемента двумерного массива - x[0][0]. А вопрос даже близко не об этом.

Comment: @Эникейщик у меня проблемы с выводом как раз этого элемента, связь очевидна)

Comment: Не очевидно. В тексте вопроса ни одного слова, про то что проблемы с этим. А только по то, что нужно вывести наиболее близкий к среднему элемент, что этот код успешно и правильно делает.

Comment: @Эникейщик "но у меня вместо элемента массива s[0][0] выводится s[1][0]", тут указано где проблема, я думаю это понятно всем кроме вас)

Comment: Я в первом же комментарии написал, почему вывод элемента [1][0] - правильный.

Comment: В следующий раз приводи минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы, а не всю простыню, где 80% к вопросу вообще не относятся, включая скриншот.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. в `s = [[0] * n] * m`  вы не создаете массив  `nxm`. Вы создаете список, содержащий m раз один и тот же список.

   ```
   n=3
   m=4
   s = [[0]*n]*m
   s
   ```

   Out[5]: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

   ```
   s[0][0]=1    
   s
   ```

   Out[7]: [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]

один из вариантов создать список списков выглядит так:

```
s = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)]
```

но лучше воспользоваться массивами из модуля [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#array-creation).  Это может быть так:

```
import numpy as np
n,m = 3,4
s = np.zeros( (m,n) )
```

Answer (score 0):

> Пусть даны два числа: количество строк n и количество столбцов m.
>   Необходимо создать список размером n×m, заполненный нулями.
>
> Очевидное решение оказывается неверным:

```
a = [[0] * m] * n
```

> В этом легко убедиться, если присвоить элементу `a[0][0]` значение 5, а
>   потом вывести значение другого элемента `a[1][0]` — оно тоже будет равно
>   5. Дело в том, что `[0] * m` возвращает ccылку на список из m нулей. Но последующее повторение этого элемента создает список из n элементов,
>   которые являются ссылкой на один и тот же список (точно так же, как
>   выполнение операции `b = a` для списков не создает новый список),
>   поэтому все строки результирующего списка на самом деле являются одной
>   и той же строкой.
>
> Источник [Создание вложенных списков](https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/2d_arrays/)

т.е. `s[0][0]` у вас одно и то же `s[1][0]`